# flutter 3.7.5 Issue on web html rendering

Tags: flutter, dart, html-rendering, flutter3.7

We are trying to upgrade our e-commerce site with multi language English and Arabic interface, but the right to left RTL text direction got missed up in *web HTML rendering* with **Flutter 3.7**

How to solve this issue? we are super excited to work on the new version of #flutter

for example:

- correct expected output:            **23.5**
- wrong web html rendering result:    **5.23**

Another example:

- correct expected output:           **(test) (هذا نص تجريبي (اختبار**
- wrong web html rendering result:     **)test() هذا نص تجريبي )اختبار**

we have tried this code sample, but it was not working

```
void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: const HomePage(),
   );
 }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Column(
       children: const [
         Directionality(
           textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
           child: Text(
             'سعر المنتج 23.5 دولار',
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
           ),
         ),
         SizedBox(height: 20),
         Directionality(
           textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
           child: Text(
             '(test) (هذا نص تجريبي (اختبار',
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question (+ format it properly)

Answer (score 0):

Your column has problem.

I fixed his problem by `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` for cover width of screen and `MainAxisAlignment.start` for start side .

If using `Directionality` as parent of widget and set `rtl` , start side always is `Right` .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: const HomePage(),
   );
 }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Directionality(
       textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
       child:Column(
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
       children: const [
          Text(
             'سعر المنتج 23.5 دولار',
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
           ),
         SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(
             '(test) (هذا نص تجريبي (اختبار',
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
           ),
       ],
     ),)
   );
 }
}
```